# Navigate to particular sidebar menu item in ShinyDashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

(cross post from shiny google groups, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/CvoABQQoZeE)

How can one navigate to a particular sidebar menu item in ShinyDashboard?

```
sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Menu Item 1")
    menuItem("Menu Item 2")
)
```

i.e. how can I put a button on the "Menu Item 1" page that will link to "Menu Item 2"?

To navigate between tabs I am using the updateTabsetPanel function:

```
observeEvent(input$go,{
updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabset1", selected = "Step 2")
})
```

I believe I should be able to use a similar function to navigate to a sidebar menu, but I am not sure what that is.

Any pointers greatly appreciated

Thanks

Iain

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? note that the example is taken from [Change the selected tab on the client](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/shinydashboard/man/updateTabItems.html)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Menu Item 1", tabName = "one", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Menu Item 1", tabName = "two", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "one",h2("Dashboard tab content"),actionButton('switchtab', 'Switch tab')),
      tabItem(tabName = "two",h2("Widgets tab content"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$switchtab, {
    newtab <- switch(input$tabs, "one" = "two","two" = "one")
    updateTabItems(session, "tabs", newtab)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: exactly, thanks. I wasn't sure on how to set the id for the sidebarMenu