# Linking to a tab or panel of a shiny app

Tags: html, r, hyperlink, shiny, href

How do I manage to link from a given shiny part to parts that are located on other tabs/panels?

### Update

The solution I drafted below works for the explicit case of linking to tabs/panels (and that's what I asked for).

**However, I'd be interested to also know about more generic ways of linking parts of a shiny app.**

### Example

I'd like to link from panel A to panel B, but I'm not quite sure what I need to specify as an action when the action link in panel A is clicked.

The value `#tab-4527-2` came from investigating the HTML output of `ui`, but I just saw that those values change each time I restart the app.

```
library(shiny)

# UI ---------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      "A",
      p(),
      actionLink("link_to_tabpanel_b", "Link to panel B")
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "B",
      h3("Some information"),
      tags$li("Item 1"),
      tags$li("Item 2")
    )
  )
)

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$link_to_tabpanel_b, {
    tags$a(href = "#tab-4527-2")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Would this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971921/navigate-to-particular-sidebar-menu-item-in-shinydashboard/32972517#32972517

Comment: @PorkChop: it does solve my immediate problem, thanks! Do you know of a more generic way to link arbitrary shiny app parts?

Comment: All the `HTML` components will have a `unique` ID assigned to them, so you can use those to link yout things together. If you want to do something complex you would need to write a bit of `Javascript`. You can have a look at example [here] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/sJlasQf71fY

Comment: I found by replacing updateTabItems() with updateTabsetPanel() you can forgo do this with only the Shiny library and you don't need to load shinydashboard. Not a big deal.

Comment: @SprengMeister: thanks, good to know that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have just released a [routing library](https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.router), which makes linking in Shiny easy. Here's how it looks like in a nutshell.

```
make_router(
   route("<your_app_url>/main",  main_page_shiny_ui),
   route("<your_app_url>/other", other_page_shiny_ui)
)
```

More information can be found in this [blog post](http://blog.appsilondatascience.com/rstats/2016/12/08/shiny.router.html).

Comment: We had to change a package name to "shiny.router". I've just changed the links in blog post. So @Rappster if you are using our library already please make sure to update your GIT configs.

Answer (score 13):

The following solution is based on the inputs I got from the comments.

Note that `updateTabsetPanel()` belongs to `shiny` while `updateTabItems()` is a function of the `shinydashboard` package. They seem to work interchangeably.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# UI ---------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "panels",
    tabPanel(
      "A",
      p(),
      actionLink("link_to_tabpanel_b", "Link to panel B")
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "B",
      h3("Some information"),
      tags$li("Item 1"),
      tags$li("Item 2"),
      actionLink("link_to_tabpanel_a", "Link to panel A")
    )
  )
)

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
#   observeEvent(input$link_to_tabpanel_b, {
#     tags$a(href = "#tab-4527-2")
#   })
  observeEvent(input$link_to_tabpanel_b, {
    newvalue <- "B"
    updateTabItems(session, "panels", newvalue)
  })
  observeEvent(input$link_to_tabpanel_a, {
    newvalue <- "A"
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "panels", newvalue)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can give your `tabsetPanel` an id and use `updateTabsetPanel` with your `observeEvent`

```
library(shiny)

# UI ---------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(id = "demo",
    tabPanel(
      "A",
      p(),
      actionLink("link_to_tabpanel_b", "Link to panel B")
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "B",
      h3("Some information"),
      tags$li("Item 1"),
      tags$li("Item 2")
    )
  )
)

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$link_to_tabpanel_b, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "demo", "B")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling with the same issue and really wanted to link to a different tab **via the URL**. Thanks to the [simple example of thesadie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43125357/7061057) and by using an *observe* to parse inputs from the url, for me the following worked (and made it possible to switch the tab by adding */?tab=B* to the URL, e.g. http://localhost:1234/?tab=B):

```
library(shiny)

# UI ---------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(id = "demo",
              tabPanel(
                "A",
                p(),
                actionLink("link_to_tabpanel_b", "Link to panel B")
              ),
              tabPanel(
                "B",
                h3("Some information"),
                tags$li("Item 1"),
                tags$li("Item 2")
              )
  )
)

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Allow url parsing
  observe({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    if (!is.null(query)) {
      for (name in names(query)) {
        if (name == "tab") {
          # Change tab
          try(updateTabsetPanel(session, "demo", selected = query[[name]]))
        } else {
          # Update inputs - this part is not really necessary if you just want to change the tabs, 
          # but I also needed to update other inputs from the url
          try(updateTextInput(session, name, value = query[[name]]), silent = TRUE)
        }
      }
    } 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$link_to_tabpanel_b, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "demo", "B")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the code and logic from Rappster. It is possible to set any kind of links. Link to `TabsetPanel` can be used by `updataTabsetPanel`. Link to `Navbar` can use `updateNavbarPage(session, inputId, selected = NULL)`. These can be found by `?updateTabsetPanel` as following.

```
updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId, selected = NULL)

updateNavbarPage(session, inputId, selected = NULL)

updateNavlistPanel(session, inputId, selected = NULL)
```

Please notice `selected` is the new id that you can define for `tabsetPanel`, `Navbar`, or `NavlistPanel`.