# Create a questionnaire with R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to learn how to create a questionnaire with Shiny. I need that each question is on a new page. For example, when the user answers to a question, press "Next" button and a new page loads with another question. Any idea on how this is done? Because I want to simplify my code, I created a module for each question. The `ui` would look like this:

```
library(shiny)

fluidPage(
  div(class = 'container',
      div(class = 'col-sm-2'),
      div(class = 'col-sm-8',
          h1("Welcome!"),
          p("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "),
          br(),
          actionButton("page1", "Start")
          )),
  source("questions/question1.R", local = TRUE)$value,
  source("questions/question2.R", local = TRUE)$value   
)
```

Module Question 1:

```
div(class = 'container',
    div(class = 'col-sm-2'),
    div(class = 'col-sm-8',
        radioButtons("question1", "Please select a number: ", choices = c(10,20,30)),
        actionButton("page3", "Next"),
        br()
    )
)
```

Module Question 2:

```
div(class = 'container',
    div(class = 'col-sm-2'),
    div(class = 'col-sm-8',
        radioButtons("question2", "Please select a color: ", choices = c("Blue", "Orange", "Red")),
        actionButton("page3", "Next"),
        br()
    )
)
```

... and the server.R:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

}
```

So, when the user press "Start" should go to page 1 and so on... Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971921/navigate-to-particular-sidebar-menu-item-in-shinydashboard/32972517#32972517

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a few ways to do this in `shiny`. I'll start with the simplest which does not solve the problem exactly and add an alternative.

*I setup the question `.R` files as per below:*

- My file path in the code is for a windows os, change as required.

Module Question 1:

```
div(class = 'container',
    div(class = 'col-sm-2'),
    div(class = 'col-sm-8',
        radioButtons("question1", "Please select a number: ", choices = c(10,20,30)),
        actionButton("block_two", "Next"),
        br()
    )
)
```

Module Question 2:

```
div(class = 'container',
    div(class = 'col-sm-2'),
    div(class = 'col-sm-8',
        radioButtons("question2", "Please select a color: ", choices = c("Blue", "Orange", "Red")),
        actionButton("block_three", "Next"),
        br()
    )
)
```

#### Simple solution

You could use the `observeEvent` and `renderUI` in `shiny`. This will allow you to pull in the neat code blocks from separate `.R` files and render them sequentially as the user clicks next.

**Note:** This however does not render the UI elements on a new page.

```
library(shiny)

ui <-  fluidPage(
  uiOutput("home"),
  uiOutput("block_one"),
  uiOutput("block_two")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$home <- renderUI({
    div(class = 'container', id = "home",
        div(class = 'col-sm-2'),
        div(class = 'col-sm-8',
            h1("Welcome!"),
            p("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "),
            br(),
            actionButton("block_one", "Start")
        ))
  })

   observeEvent(input$block_one, {
     output$block_one <- renderUI({ source("questions\\question1.R", local = TRUE)$value })
   })

  observeEvent(input$block_two, {
    output$block_two <- renderUI({ source("questions\\question2.R", local = TRUE)$value })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Intricate Solution

This requires you to create a `render_page` function which one can then use to render these new UI components on a new page. You then just need to create a function for each component and call `renderUI`.

I am not a massive fan of this as you will then need to create navigation buttons, and then might as well use `shinydashboard`.

However, if you are planning on creating a really long questionnaire then one could do the below:

*I've left the `function(...)` as is in case you would like to pass additional arguments when rendering the UI components.*

```
library(shiny)

ui <- (htmlOutput("page"))

home <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
      div(class = 'container', id = "home",
          div(class = 'col-sm-2'),
          div(class = 'col-sm-8',
              h1("Welcome!"),
              p("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "),
              br(),
              actionButton("block_one", "Start")
          ))

}

question_one <- function(...) {
  renderUI({ source("questions\\question1.R", local = TRUE)$value })
}

question_two <- function(...) {
  renderUI({ source("questions\\question2.R", local = TRUE)$value })
}

render_page <- function(...,f, title = "test_app") {
  page <- f(...)
  renderUI({
    fluidPage(page, title = title)
  })
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ## render default page
  output$page <- render_page(f = home)

     observeEvent(input$block_one, {
       output$page <- render_page(f = question_one)
     })

     observeEvent(input$block_two, {
       output$page <- render_page(f = question_two)
     })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

There is a decent r-blogger post on creating this architecture:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/some-thoughts-on-shiny-open-source-render-multiple-pages/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks RK1. It helped quite a lot!